# masking a text with a one of image and one of div background color

Tags: html, css, svg, webkit, background-image

My problem here is that I want to make a half in the text wherein the the other side of text is just a div with a background color and other half is an image so that I can mask it in a text.
Here is the sample code.

```css
.title {
          font-size: 75px;
          display:flex;
          align-items:center;
          justify-content:center;
            word-break: break-word;
            text-align: center;
            z-index: 1;
              padding:10px;
            }
            .box {
                z-index: -1;
                position: absolute;
                width: 50%;
                height: 100%;
                left: 0;
                background: #83CBFF;
            }
            img {
                object-fit: cover;
                z-index: -1;
                position: absolute;
                width: 50%;
                height: 100%;
                right: 0;
            }
```

```html
<div class="title col-auto">
 <div class="box"></div>
 <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cb/The_Blue_Marble_%28remastered%29.jpg/640px-The_Blue_Marble_%28remastered%29.jpg" alt="">
 EARTH
</div>
```

As far as I know I can only do something like this let say..one

```css
.title {
          font-size: 75px;
          display:flex;
          align-items:center;
          justify-content:center;
            word-break: break-word;
            text-align: center;
            z-index: 1;
              padding:10px;
              background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cb/The_Blue_Marble_%28remastered%29.jpg/640px-The_Blue_Marble_%28remastered%29.jpg') 50% 50%/cover;
            -webkit-background-clip: text;
            -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
            }
```

```html
<div class="title col-auto">
         EARTH
    </div>
```

But I want to cut it in both sides so it looks incredible...(In other thoughts I'm thinking about using SVG about it but still doesn't make it till work since it is not `-webkit-transparent` to the text. So anyone can help me? Thanks for any response.

Also I'm thinking maybe it can be done by something like this in `.title`

```
            background: url(./images/earth.png),linear-gradient(to top,red ,blue ) 50% 50%/cover;
            // -webkit-background-clip: text;
            // -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

but it will not workout that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correct, an example in SVG could look like this. Here I use the text as a mask on the image and rectangle.

```html
<svg xmlns="http//www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 20">
  <defs>
    <mask id="text">
      <text x="50" y="10" text-anchor="middle"
        dominant-baseline="middle" font-size="18"
        font-weight="bold" fill="white">EARTH</text>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <g mask="url(#text)">
    <image x="40" y="-20" width="60" height="50"
    href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cb/The_Blue_Marble_%28remastered%29.jpg/640px-The_Blue_Marble_%28remastered%29.jpg"/>
    <rect width="50" height="20" fill="#83CBFF"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```